# Laravel 5 class inheritance

Tags: php

I am working with laravel 5 code.

I cannot seem to extend class that has different namespace than child class.

My parent class is
The folder is App/Http/Controllers/

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class MainController extends BaseController{

    function __construct() {

    }            

    function home() {
         echo "main";
    }


}
```

And my child class is
The folder is App/Http/Controllers/Site

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site;

class SiteController extends MainController {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
    }

    function home() {

        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

And my routes file has this route

```
Route::get('/', 'Site\SiteController@home');
```

This is the error that I get

```
 FatalErrorException in SiteController.php line 5: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Site\MainController' not found
```

This clearly is the issue with namespace because when I do

```
Route::get('/', 'Site\SiteController@home');
```

It echos the method home in `MainController`

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Well, why don't you simply `use` the namespace?

Comment: @RoyalBg  

`use App\Http\Controller;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;`

I used these in MainController but did not help.

Comment: This is in your parent class file. You have a problem in your child class file. You can use there `App\Http\Controllers\MainController`

Comment: Thanks it worked..never really worked with namespaces before so a lot of confusion, laravel 5 is forcing me to learn that i got that going  for me, which is nice :)

Comment: use full namespace after the extends keyword

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not Laravel 5 problem but the common PHP namespace problem.

There are two ways to achieve the result:

- use `use` statement: add this line `use \App\Http\Controllers\MainController;`
- use full namespace: change your line to `class SiteController extends \App\Http\Controllers\MainController`

Choose the way you like more.